# C# Redundant Delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

```
public delegate T GetObject<T>(SqlDataReader reader);
public delegate KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> GetObject<TKey, TValue>(SqlDataReader reader);
```

Is it possible for removing that 2nd line (the two lines are on consecutive lines) to ever make any difference at all, superficial or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely - anything which is trying to declare a value of type `GetObject<string,string>` will fail to compile, for example.

Now, you can certainly replace any *use* of `GetObject<TKey,TValue>` with `GetObject<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` (if you see what I mean) but you can't just remove the second line.

You should also be careful of the case where this is used by reflection. It may well not be a problem in your case, but it's an easy way for a breaking change to only be visible at execution time rather than being picked up by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Can it make a difference.  Most definitely.  Removing this delegate definition will cause the formerly valid code to be a compilation error.

```
var x = new GetObject<int,String>(SomeFunction);
```